# Color of anchor tag is different in safari

Tags: html, css, browser, safari

I am using the following color code for anchor tag in my website #f195be. The anchor tag changes color in all other browsers except safari. Why is this happening? Is there a way to overcome this problem? Thanks!

Comment: In order to help you we need more information. What do you mean by _anchor tag changes color_ (`:hover`, a script)? How do you change it? How do you apply the styles(selectors, inline)?

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me :

```
a {
    color:#f195be;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/624L9vhb/

Are you using a particular version of Safari? Desktop or mobile?